# Block maxima estimation of Expected Shortfall

Tags: value-at-risk, evt

I want to calculate the expected shortfall of a return series with the block maxima  (BM, [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3222.pdf)) method in Extreme Value Theory, however I can't seem to find out how this should be done. All papers I've found only consider the peak over threshold (POT) method where it can be calculated via

$$ ES_q = \frac{VaR_q}{1-\gamma} + \frac{\beta - \gamma u}{1-\gamma}$$
Where $\gamma$ is the GPD shape parameter, $\beta$ the scale parameter and $u$ the threshold. I reckon that it must be possible to use this with the BM method as well, as the GPD (Generalized Pareto Distribution) is a special case of the limit to the GEV (Generalized Extreme Value Distribution) (Am I right?). However, I can't seem to find any paper which calculated ES with the BM method so I'm a bit stuck right now. Is it possible to use this expression for the BM method as well? If yes, what do I need to fill in for the threshold $u$?

I found the expression for the POT ES in McNeil (1999): *Extreme Value Theory for Risk Managers*, but it's stated in many other papers and books as well.

Answer (score 1):

We can define the algorithm of Expected Shortfall (ES) based on Block Maxima Method as follows:

[image]

Where *α* is the scale, *ξ* is the shape parameter and *β* is the location. All of them, parameters of the GEV distribution.
Where *n* is the block size and *p* the probability.

You can find the complete proof in Ou &Yi (2009): *“Robustness Analysis and Algorithm of Expected Shortfall Based on Extreme-Value Block Minimum Model”*.

I hope it helps.